# How do I kick-off n child processes and a "stopwatch" process; only stopping the stopwatch when the active processes have finished?

Tags: linux, bash, wait

I want to test how long the overall process takes, when its been split into 3,4,5 or more parallel processes.
I need to display and log each split process.
I have written/borrowed a script to launch 3 child processes, which sleep; the parent process should `wait $PID` before continuing, BUT I can't get this part to work, any help is welcome?
so here's the code
**multi_load.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

WORK_DIR=`pwd`
echo ${WORK_DIR}

pids=(); 
for((i=0;i<3;i++)); 
do
    mate-terminal --window --command "$WORK_DIR/sl.sh $i" &
    echo "process $! $? " ;
    pids+=( $! );
done; 

echo "Array ${pids[@]}" ;

for pid in ${pids[@]}; 
do 
    echo "Check ${pid}" ;
    wait ${pid};                 # THIS IS NOT WORKING
    echo ret=$?; 
done;

echo "finish";

exit
```

**sl.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#exec >&1 | tee slp-${1}\.log
exec &> >(tee -a "slp-${1}.log")

echo "sleep $1" ;
new_time=$((($1*3)+15)) ;
echo "new $new_time" ;
sleep $new_time ;
exit $(($1+42)) ;
```

To recap;

1. the parent process doesn't wait for the child processes to finish
   before exiting
2. I need a stopwatch process to visibily show the time taken
   Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `time` command could be useful to know how much time it takes.  No clue for the wait.

Comment: UPDATE: if I remove the use of ```mate-terminal --window --command``` and just keep the call to ```sl.sh $i``` ; the wait command works! So my problem appears to be with the way the o/s handles child processes when calling MATE!